# Proof by induction for a recursive sum

Tags: induction, recursion

I have a homework assignment that has made my head hurt for the past several days. I found no explanation on the materials provided by the Professor on this matter. I'm given:

$$
sum: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\\
\begin{align}
s1&:sum(0, y)=y\\
s2&:sum(x+1, y)=sum(x,y)+1
\end{align}
$$

And the Prof. wants me to prove that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}:sum(x,y)=sum(y,x)$.

My induction basis is $P(0)=sum(0, y)=sum(y,0)$, which, by commutativity, is valid.

My induction hypothesis: $HI:sum(x,y)=sum(y,x)$.

I really am stuck. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Not even the Isabelle proofer could help me figure this out...

Comment: 'by commutativity' - of what? Start with $\text{sum}(y,0)$ and justify (use s2 repeatedly) why that must equal $\text{sum}(0,y) = y$. That should hint you toward the induction step.

Comment: I'm... at a total loss... How would I go from $sum(y,0)$ to  $sum(0,y)$? I'm really, really sorry, I just don't understand this part of mathmatics.

Comment: You could do the induction for $x+1$ and $y+1$ separately.  Proving that if $sum(x,y) = sum(y,x)$ then prove both $sum(x+1,y) = sum(y,x+1)$ and $sum(x,y+1) = sum(y+1,x)$.

Comment: Try proving sum(x,y) = x+y. Then commutativity follows after. Induction is not on x or y, it is on x+y

Comment: I've already proven $sum(x,y)=x+y$, $sum(x,0)=x$ and $sum(0,x)=x$ :( I'm feeling more stupid by the second

Comment: so sum(x,y) = x+y = y+x = sum(y,x) which is the whole thing required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do induction within induction.

What I mean is, since the claim to be proved is $\forall x \ \forall y \ sum(x,y) = sum(y,x)$, you can set up the 'outer' inductive proof on variable $x$ as:

Base: Show that $\forall y \ sum(0,y) = sum(y,0)$

Step:  Let $n$ be some arbitrary number, and show that if $\forall y \ sum(n,y) = sum(y,n)$, then  $\forall y \ sum(n+1,y) = sum(y,n+1)$

Now, to show the Base $\forall y \ sum(0,y) = sum(y,0)$ of this outer induction, you can;t just say, as you do, 'by commutativity'.  In fact, some sort of commutativity is the very thing we are proving over and over here.  Anyway, to prove this, we can do induction on the variable $y$:

'Base's Base':  Show that $sum(0,0)=sum(0,0)$

'Base's Step': Let $m$ be some arbitrary number, and show that if $sum(0,m) = sum(m,0)$, then $sum(0,m+1) = sum(m+1,0)$

Likewise, to prove the 'outside' Step (if $\forall y \ sum(n,y) = sum(y,n)$, then  $\forall y \ sum(n+1,y) = sum(y,n+1)$) we can use induction. To be specific, once we have assumed that $\forall y \ sum(n,y) = sum(y,n)$, we can show that $\forall y \ sum(n+1,y) = sum(y,n+1)$ by induction on the $y$:

'Step's Base': Show that $sum(n+1,0) = sum(0,n+1)$

'Step's Step': Let $m$ be some arbitrary number, and show that if $sum(n+1,m) = sum(m,n+1)$, then $sum(n+1,m+1) = sum(m+1,n+1)$

Comment: I'm trying my hardest to prove the inner induction's step ($sum(0,y+1)=sum(y+1,0)$) but I'm getting nowhere...

Comment: Well, sum(0,y+1)=y+1.  On the other hand, sum(y+1,0)=sum(y,0)+1. But since by inductive hypothesis we have sum(y,0)=sum(0,y), that means sum(y+1,0)=sum(0,y)+1=y+1. So, we have that sum(0,y+1)=sum(y+1,0). ... the moral: make use of that inductive hypothesis!!  That is, remember that you ate showing that *if* sum(y,0)=sum(0,y), *then* sum(y+1,0) =sum(0, y+1)

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I've gotten to the point of proving the ' Step's Base', and yet again I am stuck...

Comment: @rafadeboas Can you add to your post what you have so far?

Comment: I just got it, actually. I applied my already-proven sum(x,y)=x+y to sum(x+1,y+1)=sum(y+1,x+1) and Isabelle did the rest (thank god). Thank you for your help, you have been wonderful!

Comment: @rafadeboas Yay! :)